# Facebook LIke Button Feature

Tags: facebook, like

I have a made a social networking website similar to Facebook. In Facebook, there is a **LIKE** Button feature that they have implemented it. Can I also use the Same name "**Like**" and program that feature too my website. Will I be vilating any copyright of Facebook.

Please note that am not talking about [Facebook Like Button Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button). I' am talking about writing the whole "Like" button code from scratch for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think you may be in the clear as far as using the word "like". If they had it protected, there would be a `™` or something similar on all their buttons and they would speak of the protection of the word in their branding found at https://www.facebookbrand.com/.

On their brand useage PDF it speaks of it in scope of an image and says the following:

`"Don't Substitute the Like Button logo for the word ‘Like’"`

So it seems they probably protected the image of the word "like", or hold the "look" of it as intellectual property, but nothing is said further about the use of the word in regards to unrelated platforms. It's up to you whether you challenge this theory in a production social network :)

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once.

Comment: @closetnoc haha thanks man. Just a note for Red Virus, there is slightly ambiguous wording found in the "Using Facebook in Your Broadcast" PDF. It talks about "wording" and imitation: `Don't use trademarks, names, domain names, logos or other
content that imitates or could be confused with Facebook`. It's hard to say what they mean here -- is "like" a literal name assimilated with FB? Perhaps just to be safe one should put a disclaimer in the footer of the production social network. Something like "the like button on this site is not affiliated with Facebook".

Comment: The OP can also avoid the whole thing and use another word and symbol. I cannot recommend one that would be universal, I do not have enough imagination for that right now, unless you want something kinda "New Yorkish". Then I might be your man.

Comment: Hah true... howabout an "enrapture" or the classic "winsome" button

Comment: I am an ex-audio engineer and audio-file with way too much money tied up in stereo's to the tune of the several 10s of k of $'s. I was thinking a volume knob and VU meter would be fun. BTW- I had a friend fall out of his chair when I told him my T.V. surround system was Aragon. I am a huge Krell fan if anyone knows what that is.

Comment: @closetnoc Dude that is awesome. Id love to own some of that stuff. The most i do rich audio is the ol Mesa/Boogie geetar rig :) As a cool note though, just bought a house and found various (N)OS sylvania power and pre tubes in the attic. I think they are for an old projector or something, not sure if they would fit any high end audiophile stuff

Comment: I have a fairly large collection of very powerful Fischer tube amps from 1947 and up with pre-amps, tuners, and so on. I have high-end tube receivers through to the 1960's. I have fairly rare shortwave radios from Europe and ham radio rx/tx stuff. I do not have a few. I have way too many. I discovered this stuff during Jr High and have restored a ton of stuff. I have one Fischer amp that is so rare, the total number was thought to be one (not working) till I chimed in and said I have two I listen to every day. I have not kept up with this stuff in the past decade, but I do love it.